# Sorting array won't work in ANSI C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I'm writing a code in ANSI C, this code has to accomplish a single, easy task:

- sort the array
- search in an array for an element
- return element position if found
- else return -1

I defined my function like this:

```
int search_sorted(int *array, int dimensione, int elemento) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<dimensione;i++){
        //fill the array with random numbers
        *(array+i)=((int)(rand()%RANDOM_MAX));
    }
    sort(array,dimensione);
    //this should actually sort the array?
    for(i=0;i<dimensione;i++){
        printf(" posizione %d\t -\t %d\n",i+1,array[i]);
        //print the array...
    }    
    for(i=0;i<dimensione;i++){
        if(elemento>array[i]){
            return -1;
        } else if(array[i] == elemento) {
        return ++i;
        }    
    }
    return -1;
}

//sorting function
int sort (int *array,int dim){
int i, temp;
for (i=0;i<(dim-1);i++){
    if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
            temp=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=array[i];
            array[i]=temp;
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the sorting simply won't apply, and I don't see a reason why it won't... I'm 100% sure I'm passing the right elements (no compiling errors nor anything...)

Any idea why it doesn't work, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to implement a bubble sort algorithm. Your implementation is not correct.
Your loop just puts the greatest element in the last position.

You need to use another loop which should nest this loop.

```
for(j=0;j<dim-1;j++)
for (i=0;i<(dim-1-j);i++){
    if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
            temp=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=array[i];
            array[i]=temp;
    }
```

Comment: okay, i googled bubble sort, and came up with something really usefull, i had no idea something like this already existed, yet i don't understand why mine won't apply (i mean, i do understand i lack a lot of iteration, but mine won't even swap a single cell...)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer was initially simply the useless "Your implementation is not correct" before you edited it, so I'm not surprised it was downvoted.

Comment: @interjay The OP didnt even know it was called Bubble sort. SO,it was not useless even at that point.

Comment: @YuriCollector'sEditionRossi How do you know your code didn't even swap a single cell?

Comment: okay thx, i now understood what i did wrong ^^ thanks for the info :)

Comment: @melpomene i indeed didn't, i just realized that the last element was always the greatest, so actually it did something... i got it working now, thx a bunch everyone ^^